# Probability- Dice related problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, dice

The problem goes like this:

A fair die is rolled till 6 shows up. The first 16 throws were unsuccessful(i.e. 6 did not show up in any of the first 16 throws), the probability that the first 6 will show up in the 19th throw is?

My attempt :

$P[Not\ getting\  a\  6]=5/6$

For calculation of total possibilities considering the first 16 unsuccessful throws, I considered the last three throws as binomial random variable $X$ where the number of $6's$ can be $0,1,2$ and $3$.

Therefore, total probability is = $(5/6)^{16}*[\binom{3}{0}*(5/6)^{3}+\binom{3}{1}*(5/6)^{2}*(1/6)+\binom{3}{2}*(5/6)^{1}*(1/6)^{2}+\binom{3}{3}*(1/6)^{3}]$

$P[getting \ 6 \ in\ the\ 19th\ throw]$=

$\frac{(5/6)^{18}*(1/6)}{(5/6)^{16}*[\binom{3}{0}*(5/6)^{3}+\binom{3}{1}*(5/6)^{2}*(1/6)+\binom{3}{2}*(5/6)^{1}*(1/6)^{2}+\binom{3}{3}*(1/6)^{3}]}$= $(5/6)^{2}*(1/6)$

Is my approach to the problem correct? Please help.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  There is a faster approach: the dice throws are memoryless so you just need the 17th and 18th throws to not be 6, and the 19th throw to be 6, which give the same answer of $\left(\frac56\right)^2\frac16$

Comment: @Henry, thanks for the faster approach!